# spring @Autowired a repository returns null

Tags: spring, annotations, autowired

I am new to spring and jpa. I have searched the similar topics and still not able to solve my issue. I tried to autowire my EmployeeRepository(Imp) in my test file, but it always return null... All the code is under the same package. Thanks a lot for your time.

Another question is that which one I should use (I had tried both with no luck)

```
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepositoryImp er;
```

and

```
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository er;
```

Below is my code...

```
    package com.rw.examples.hibernate_ogm_neo4j;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    @Configuration
    public class AppConfig {

        @Bean
        public EntityManager entityManager() {
            return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        }

        @Bean
        public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
            return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ogm-neo4j");
        }

    }



    package com.rw.examples.hibernate_ogm_neo4j;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    @Repository
    public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{

    }




    package com.rw.examples.hibernate_ogm_neo4j;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    @Repository
    public class EmployeeRepositoryImp extends SimpleJpaRepository<Employee, Long> implements EmployeeRepository{

        private EntityManager entityManager;

        @Autowired
        public EmployeeRepositoryImp(Class<Employee> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
            super(domainClass, em);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.entityManager = em;
        }
    }



    package com.rw.examples.hibernate_ogm_neo4j;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

    @Controller
    @EnableJpaRepositories (basePackages = {"com.rw.examples.hibernate_ogm_neo4j"})
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.rw.examples.hibernate_ogm_neo4j"})
    public class RepositoryTest {


    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepositoryImp er;

    @Test
    public void testRepository() {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

        EntityManagerFactory emf = ctx.getBean(EntityManagerFactory.class);
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


        System.out.println("testRepository");
        er.save(new Employee("Frank"));
        System.out.println("list employees using repository");
        Iterable<Employee> employees = er.findAll();
        employees.forEach(e->System.out.println(e.toString()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved the problem. To run JUNIT test, need to use @RunWith.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=AppConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class RepositoryTest {...}
```

And also in the AppConfig.java need to have the following annotation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class AppConfig {...}
```

finally, it seems like hibernate ogm doesn't work well with jparepository. still studying...

Comment: If you are using Spring then I recommend you give [Spring Data Neo4j](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j) a try. It is backed by both the developers behind Neo4j and Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a concrete implementation of EmployeeRepository. Comment out that class and autowire EmployeeRepository.

Also you don't need @Controller annotation on the Test.

Comment: EmployeeRepository is null because spring is unable to do dependency injection which could be many reasons from component scan not scanning all packages or nested dependencies failing. I would recommend to use a maven based directory structure and use SpringBootTest to test your repositories.